# Any way to alter text attributes within a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uifont

Simply stated -
I want to have a scrollable text field with a paragraph of text.  Some of the sentences should be bold and blue while others are red and normal, while the remainder is simple black/normal text.

Any way to alter the text attributes 'within / amongst' the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A lie for your sanity: no, you cannot
  do this.
- The truth (use with caution): You can
  create attributed strings... using
  core text (but just don't even bother
  lol - its not worth it).
- The compromise: Use a UIWebView and
  HTML. :) Can't say fairer than that.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  I had not considered that.  Should be perfect.